# Suggest that close votes be restricted to members with relevant tag expertise

Tags: feature-request

netlogo is a specialist programming language that has terms that look odd to general language programmers. This means that questions can attract close votes for being broad even if the question makes perfect sense to a netlogo programmer. I imagine this is a problem for some other tags as well.

I suggest that the reputation requirement for voting to close be tag specific. At the moment, the close vote privilege is earned at 3,000 reputation. I suggest it be earned at tag specific 1000 reputation. Reputation by tag is already tracked so it can be done in principle.

Comment: Do you have some examples?

Comment: The same could generally be said for almost any two languages.  Some knowledge in vbscript for instance doesnt lend much to C++ or python tagged questions.  It is more about skipping review Qs you know you have little expertise in.

Comment: I did have some examples when I first noticed the problem - but I can't access them because they are closed

Comment: @JenB Closed or deleted? Closed questions should still show up, though deleted ones won't. You also seem to be confusing "too broad" and "unclear what you're asking". A question can make perfect sense to a netlogo programmer and still be too broad. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594663/netlogo-turtles-move-directly-to-another-turtle-when-in-range) seems like a perfect example of a question that really needs to be clarified further. The answer starts with the word "Suppose", so they're having to make guesses and assumptions before they can start answering the question.

Comment: I don't think I could have picked a better example, considering what I just saw happen... He asked a broad question, received an answer, and now he's adding more information (in an answer!) and asking a follow up question so he can continue to solve problems. This guy needs educating on what this site is for, and that's not to just write his code for him every time he gets the tiniest bit stuck. You might be willing to accept crap like that in your tag, but that doesn't mean we should be willing to accept it on our site.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Possibly deleted. Yes, that is the question that reminded me, but it's not one of the ones that made me notice the problem in the first place. netlogo is also a language with a lot of newbies (and homework seekers) because it has a strong education base, so we tend to be fairly tolerant of questions without attempted code.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Someone will (usually) respond and ask him to start a new thread.

Comment: Many questions can be clearly identified as bad without any technical skill or experience whatsover in the language/s or whatever that are tagged.

Comment: @JenB someone should have responded after the question was asked and closed it, as it's not a specific programming question but a request for somebody else to do their work. And if you're "fairly tolerant" of users who just want their homework solved, then you're part of the problem. SO has way too many people already who answer all kinds of crap just because it's answerable, but that is not the goal of this site. The goal is to create a high quality knowledge repository with questions useful to more people than just OP; not to help every individual who is too lazy to even attempt something.

Comment: @l4mpi Sorry, I wasn't clear. Tolerant of questions asking 'how do I' which may be someone not able to work out which primitive to use, not tolerant of homework

Comment: @jenB just a question : how do we deal with new tags before enough users have CV privileges?

Comment: I've cast 563 close votes. With your suggestion, I'd have cast none. No questions would ever have been closed in any of my favourite tags. Sorry, but a silly idea in this form.

Comment: Questions with no clear problem statement, code with single-letter vars, no inputs, no outputs, no error-messages and/or no attempt at debugging are bad.  You don't need any specific skill or experience to identify such questions as bad.  Many experienced SO contributors can smell a bad question just from the title, (some can be answered just from the title:).

Comment: Lack of knowledge about a tag does not indicate lack of ability to identify questions that should be closed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I disagree with this suggestion. Close votes are taking enough time as it is.

With this restriction, I would *only* be able to close [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) questions on SO, and *no* questions on meta, as you can see from this screenshot from my profile:

[image]
<sub>(My top 3 tags on SO. On Meta, my highest scored tag is 651)</sub>

Also, a feature like this could ***easily*** be abused. Just add some tag to your question that kindof applies to it, but barely has any questions. Voilá, no-one can close-vote your question!

Unless the feature only looks at tags *currently* on the question, but then the restriction could easily be circumvented with a quick tag edit.

Comment: If the question has multiple tags, then the voter would only require reputation in any of the tags. So the only way that could be abused is if the question only had that rare tag, and then it probably wouldn't be seen. Alternatively, a higher reputation could allow close votes regardless.

Comment: So if you add a relatively generic tag, people with no knowledge of the language used in the question, would be able to close the question. Then what's the point of this feature?

Comment: @JenB in that case the close process will become: add my favourite tag, vote to close, remove my favourite tag in order to close complete nonsense questions on rare tags. E.g. please recommend a tool to do X

Comment: I agree that it's a bad suggestion, but OP is talking about 1k _rep_ from the tag, not 1k _score_ (which would mean >=10k rep) - you would still be able to close regex questions. TL;DR you're too focussed on the amount of rep instead of all the other things wrong with this proposal.

Comment: Okay, it's clear that this is an unpopular suggestion. I don't believe it would be as hard to get relevant reputation as suggested by this screenshot - my top tag is netlogo with a score of 56 but my reputation earned on netlogo questions is my full 846. So score and reputation are not the same thing. Nevertheless, this is the concern of everyone except me, so it is clearly the best answer.

Comment: @l4mpi: Rep is 1 of 4 things wrong with this suggestion that I mention in the answer, but you're right about rep vs score.

Answer (score 11):

In my experience what tags that deal with less popular topics need is *more people voting to close*, not less. It is a shame when a blatant request for an external resource does not get closed because not enough people visit the tag. This proposal would just exacerbate this problem.

There would also be a "bootstrapping" problem. If I've just created [foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo) for the newfangled `foo` library, there's no one on SO that has enough reputation to close anything in this tag, except moderators, but we should not put this extra burden on them.

This would also allow the creation of de facto exceptions to the topicness rules. If only a few people have the power to close questions in a given tag, they can decide to not apply some of the close reasons. Lest you think this is a fanciful scenario: we have had people arguing for exceptions to the topicness rules for certain tags on this Meta and on Meta.SE. There was one recently who basically argued that his favorite language is soooooo special that requests for libraries should be allowed for this language.

Comment: +1, I particularly agree with the last paragraph.

Comment: The top three scores across any of my favourite tags are  are 515, 405, and 155. That's six main tags where *nothing* could ever be closed. Non-starter, as you indicate.